# Why is CHAR_BIT usually 8?

Tags: c++

According to `N4140`(C++11 working draft):

> The fundamental storage unit in the C ++ memory model is the byte. A byte is at least large enough to contain any member of the basic execution character set and the eight-bit code units of the Unicode UTF-8 encoding form and is composed of a contiguous sequence of bits, the number of which is implementation-defined. (§6.6.1-1; p.48)

I think 8 bits are needed only to contain all members of "the eight-bit code units of the Unicode UTF-8 encoding form". Aren't more bits needed also to contain all members of "the basic execution character set"? Why can `CHAR_BIT` be 8 in many implementations?

Comment: There are 96 characters in the basic execution character set, which only requires 7 bits

Comment: @M.M Then, at least 9 bits are needed, aren't they? For example, if the first member of UTF-8 is represented as `00000001` and the last member is represented as `11111111`, aren't more bits needed to represent a member of the basic execution character set?

Comment: @ynn: There are no characters in the basic instruction set that are not in ASCII, which represents the first 127 characters of UTF-8.

Comment: The quote you provided answers half of it: "*and the eight-bit code units of the Unicode UTF-8 encoding*", so it must be *at least* 8 bits. Now the rest is the basic execution character set which requires 7 bits. `max(7,8)=8`.

Comment: Anything other than 8, would sure throw a wrench in the x86_64 thing (x86_56?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic execution set contains 96 characters, not one of which is outside of the ASCII character set. And UTF-8's first 127 characters *are* ASCII.

So no, there is no need for `char` to be bigger than 8 bits, on the basis of the basic execution set characters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then, why is "basic execution character set" referred in the draft? If UTF-8 contains all members of it, I think it's enough only to refer to UTF-8.

Comment: @ynn: Because implementations are not *required* to use UTF-8/ASCII as their character set *encoding*. Whatever encoding they want to use, they have to provide those characters. But it doesn't have to be any particular encoding. The point here is that the character set encoding, either ASCII, UTF-8, or something implementation-defined for the execution character set, does not in any way force an implementation to need more than 8 bits for `char`.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand why you are talking about what kind of encoding the implementation takes. If, as you told me, the basic execution character set is a subset of 8-bit code units of UTF-8, and if all members of the two sets have to be included in `char` (with "any" encoding), is there any need to refer to the former set?

Comment: @ynn: The term "character set" refers to a group of characters. But the assignment of a *value* to a character in a set is an *encoding*. Different encodings can assign the same conceptual character to a different value. The basic execution character set contains 96 characters, and therefore could be encoded in 8 bits. But there is no *requirement* that the encoding for it be ASCII or UTF-8. That's why the standard cannot simply "refer to UTF-8". UTF-8 is an *encoding* of the Unicode character set. That's why we're talking about encodings.

Answer (score 9):

The *basic execution character* set is defined as follows (emphasis mine):

> [**[lex.charset]/3**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.charset#3)
>
> **The *basic execution character set* and the *basic execution
>   wide-character set* shall each contain all the members of the basic
>   source character set, plus control characters representing alert,
>   backspace, and carriage return, plus a null character (respectively,
>   null wide character), whose value is 0.** For each basic execution
>   character set, the values of the members shall be non-negative and
>   distinct from one another. In both the source and execution basic
>   character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list
>   of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.
>   The *execution character set* and the *execution wide-character set* are
>   implementation-defined supersets of the basic execution character set
>   and the basic execution wide-character set, respectively. The values
>   of the members of the execution character sets and the sets of
>   additional members are locale-specific.

Where the basic source character set is this:

> [**[lex.charset]/1**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.charset#3)
>
> The *basic source character set* consists of 96 characters: the space
>   character, the control characters representing horizontal tab,
>   vertical tab, form feed, and new-line, plus the following 91 graphical
>   characters:
>
> ```
> a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
> A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> _ { } [ ] # ( ) < > % : ; . ? * + - / ^ & | ~ ! = , \ " '
> ```

Note the difference between the *basic* execution character set, as defined by the standard, and the implementation defined execution character set. The former contains about 100 characters only, and the encoding for those (whichever it is) can fit in 8 bits quite well.

One must also exercise caution when reading the paragraph in your question. A byte needs to be large enough to hold the encoding of a character in the basic execution character set *or* a utf-8 char. The former encoding may be (and often *is*) a subset of the later, but even though it doesn't have to be, 8 bits suffices as a minimum either way.

Comment: *implementation defined execution character set* Does this cover characters outside ascii range?What possible example of this could be.

Comment: @GauravSehgal - Even just supporting all of ASCII fits the bill. Since ASCII contains more than 100 different character encodings.

Answer (score 0):

C has a definition of the type char, and the language specification basically uses the terms char and  byte interchangeably. Historically, in times there have been platforms with chars (and thus bytes) that had a width different from 8, in particular some early computers coded printable characters with only 6 bits and had a word size of 36. And later other constructors found it more convenient to have words of 16 bits to be the least addressable unit.

So, in C90 it was defined that:

> **The number of bits in a char is defined in the macro CHAR_BIT
>  CHAR_BIT can be any value but must be at least 8**

Even in C99 it is stated that:

> **A byte contains CHAR_BIT bits, and the values of type unsigned char range from 0 to (2^CHAR_BIT) – 1.**

But then, on the page for the include file stdint.h it states:

> **The typedef name int N _t designates a signed integer type with width
>   N, no  padding  bits,  and  a  two’s-complement representation. Thus,
>   int8_t denotes a signed integer type with a width of exactly 8 bits.**

So far so good, if there is an int8_t we can deduce that sizeof(int8_t) must be 1 and CHAR_BIT must be 8. 
But then the POSIX standard says, the following types are required:

- int8_t
- int16_t
- int32_t
- uint8_t
- uint16_t
- uint32_t

Which forces CHAR_BIT to be 8, and basically also implies that at least for small width types the representation must be two’s-complement on any POSIX compatible platform

[Source](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/06/01/how-many-bits-has-a-byte/)